# Cannot locate VS 2015 Enterprise executable

Tags: visual-c++

Installed VS 2015 Enterprise in location 
C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0

From previous posts with other versions it is supposed to be in the Common\IDE folder somewhere. In Control Panel it already shows as installed. Can't locate it.

Comment: Does this help you?
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\
Maybe: devenv.exe

Comment: Thanks @dorad.I restarted VS Community 2015 and it was updated to Enterprise. That's were i wanted to go to. These updates an/or downloads are not so easily understood.

Comment: Glad to hear. Was that the right path?

Comment: @dorad@peter or @PeterSmith.You were exactly right. That's the correct path. After upgrading to VS Enterprise after a VS Community installation, you can just click on that devenv.exec file and it should automatically initialize it to  'Enterprise' version. Your advise is correct. Otherwise after upgrading to 'Enterprise', just restart computer and start VS from whatever version your using. It should start from 'VS Enterprise'.

Comment: So if it helped you, consider mark the below answer as correct. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

As said in comments, the path is:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
```